# Xcode display default selected table cell

Tags: xcode, default, uitableview

I want to display a default cell during FIRST time tableView loading. I know a method like below but don't know where should I put that. My default cell is out of range from  `willDisplayCell`.

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:defaultIndexPath
                            animated:YES
                      scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

For example my TableView dataSource have 20 rows, but my tableView size only can fit 6rows. I wish to scroll and selected the row number 12 when I first loading the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use method viewWillAppear or instead of this call [cell setSelected:YES] in method 
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]

Comment: the indexPath in '[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]' haven't reach my default cell when viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear

Comment: maybe I should get indexPath for selected cell manually before loading tableView?

Comment: Do you want to select specific cell or just scroll to this cell? Because i'm not sure what you want achieve?

Comment: For example my TableView dataSource have 20 rows, but my tableView size only can fit 6rows. I wish to scroll and selected the row number 12 when I first loading the tableView.